# Why does not @EntityGraph annotation in JPA need to use "distinct" keyword or "Set" data structure?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I found out some interesting thing.
When `@OneToMany` relationship in JPA, there should be N+1 issues.
We need to use `fetch join` in JPQL or `@EntityGraph` annotation to avoid performance issue.
But, we encounter other problem which is overlapping entities because of `Cartesian product`.
`fetch join` becomes `inner join` and `@EntityGraph` becomes `left outer join` in SQL.
So we have to using `distinct` in JPQL or `Set` data structure in Java.

Here is my question.
When using `fetch join`, there is overlapping entities problem.
However, when using `@EntityGraph` annotation, we can't see overlapping entities problem.

Let me show you a example.
Here is my data set.

| post.id | post.content | post.title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | this is the first post. | first post |

| reply.id | reply.content | reply.post_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first-reply-1 | 1 |
| 2 | first-reply-2 | 1 |
| 3 | first-reply-3 | 1 |
| 4 | first-reply-4 | 1 |
| 5 | first-reply-5 | 1 |
| 6 | first-reply-6 | 1 |
| 7 | first-reply-7 | 1 |
| 8 | first-reply-8 | 1 |
| 9 | first-reply-9 | 1 |
| 10 | first-reply-10 | 1 |

And when we query like this.

```sql
select *
from test.post inner join test.reply on test.post.id = test.reply.post_id;
```

We expect data like this.
But `@EntityGraph` annotation doesn't work like this.

| post.id | post.content | post.title | reply.id | reply.content | reply.post_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | this is the first post. | first post | 1 | first-reply-1 | 1 |
| 1 | this is the first post. | first post | 2 | first-reply-2 | 1 |
| 1 | this is the first post. | first post | 3 | first-reply-3 | 1 |
| 1 | this is the first post. | first post | 4 | first-reply-4 | 1 |
| 1 | this is the first post. | first post | 5 | first-reply-5 | 1 |
| 1 | this is the first post. | first post | 6 | first-reply-6 | 1 |
| 1 | this is the first post. | first post | 7 | first-reply-7 | 1 |
| 1 | this is the first post. | first post | 8 | first-reply-8 | 1 |
| 1 | this is the first post. | first post | 9 | first-reply-9 | 1 |
| 1 | this is the first post. | first post | 10 | first-reply-10 | 1 |

##### Test Code

###### Post Entity

```java
package blog.in.action.post;

import blog.in.action.reply.Reply;
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @Column
    private String content;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
    private List<Reply> replies;

    public void addReply(Reply reply) {
        if (replies == null) {
            replies = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        replies.add(reply);
    }
}
```

###### Reply Entity

```java
package blog.in.action.reply;

import blog.in.action.post.Post;
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Reply {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String content;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    private Post post;
}
```

###### PostRepository repository

```java
package blog.in.action.post;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.EntityGraph;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT p FROM Post p JOIN FETCH p.replies WHERE p.title = :title")
    List<Post> findByTitleFetchJoinWithoutDistinct(String title);

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"replies"})
    @Query(value = "SELECT p FROM Post p WHERE p.title = :title")
    List<Post> findByTitleEntityGraphWithoutDistinct(String title);
}
```

###### PostRepositoryTest tests

```java
package blog.in.action.post;

import blog.in.action.reply.Reply;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;

@DataJpaTest
public class PostRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    Post getPost(String title, String content) {
        return Post.builder()
                .title(title)
                .content(content)
                .build();
    }

    void insertReply(Post post, String content) {
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            Reply reply = Reply.builder()
                    .content(content + index)
                    .post(post)
                    .build();
            post.addReply(reply);
            em.persist(reply);
        }
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {

        Post post = getPost("first post", "this is the first post.");
        Post secondPost = getPost("second post", "this is the second post.");

        postRepository.save(post);
        postRepository.save(secondPost);

        insertReply(post, "first-reply-");
        insertReply(secondPost, "second-reply-");

        em.flush();
        em.clear();
    }

    @Test
    public void whenFindByTitleFetchJoinWithoutDistinct_thenJustOneQuery() {

        List<Post> posts = postRepository.findByTitleFetchJoinWithoutDistinct("first post");

        assertThat(posts.size()).isEqualTo(10);
    }

    @Test
    public void whenFindByTitleEntityGraphWithoutDistinct_thenJustOneQuery() {

        List<Post> posts = postRepository.findByTitleEntityGraphWithoutDistinct("first post");

        assertThat(posts.size()).isEqualTo(1);
    }
}
```

###### whenFindByTitleFetchJoinWithoutDistinct_thenJustOneQuery test

- log

```sql
select post0_.id         as id1_0_0_,
       replies1_.id      as id1_1_1_,
       post0_.content    as content2_0_0_,
       post0_.title      as title3_0_0_,
       replies1_.content as content2_1_1_,
       replies1_.post_id as post_id3_1_1_,
       replies1_.post_id as post_id3_1_0__,
       replies1_.id      as id1_1_0__
from post post0_
         inner join reply replies1_ on post0_.id = replies1_.post_id
where post0_.title = ?
```

- debug result
  [image]

###### whenFindByTitleEntityGraphWithoutDistinct_thenJustOneQuery test

- log

```sql
select post0_.id         as id1_0_0_,
       replies1_.id      as id1_1_1_,
       post0_.content    as content2_0_0_,
       post0_.title      as title3_0_0_,
       replies1_.content as content2_1_1_,
       replies1_.post_id as post_id3_1_1_,
       replies1_.post_id as post_id3_1_0__,
       replies1_.id      as id1_1_0__
from post post0_
         left outer join reply replies1_ on post0_.id = replies1_.post_id
where post0_.title = ?
```

- debug result
  [image]

Is there someone to know about this?

###### Full test code link

- https://github.com/Junhyunny/blog-in-action/tree/master/2022-01-15-jpa-one-plus-n-problem/action-in-blog

Comment: Good question, I was wondering the exact same thing. I suspect that the duplicates are filtered out somewhere within the Hibernate implementation, on the asumption that is what the user wants (in most cases). **EDIT:** Opened up a bounty, maybe we can get some answers.

Comment: It's a know "feature" that JOIN FETCH returns duplicates.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: The point of the question (as I understand it) is that with `@EntityGraph`, this widely known "feature" that you mention, does not in fact apply. It's good that it works this way, but it's also somewhat confusing; hence OPs question.

Comment: I know. But EntityGraph is simply not the same as JOIN FETCH. With JOIN FETCH you get the result from the JDBC ResultSet. EntityGraph is a way to tell what Hibernate should load

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: Ok, no problem. Yes, I was thinking the same thing. Maybe someone who's more at-home with the inner workings of Hibernate can find a docs reference or point it out specifically in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Entity Graphs distinct applies by default. Filtering performs on the java side by the framework using Identity Set.

It was implemented in 5.2.10 version [HHH-11569](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11569?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aworklog-tabpanel)

See [source code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/ab28812a7d287156f3856170aded9b59006cffaa/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/hql/internal/ast/QueryTranslatorImpl.java#L376)

```java
org/hibernate/hql/internal/ast/QueryTranslatorImpl.java

public List list(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
            throws HibernateException {
...
        final boolean needsDistincting = (
                query.getSelectClause().isDistinct() ||
                getEntityGraphQueryHint() != null ||  //In case query has Entity Graph HINT applies distincting of result records
                hasLimit )
        && containsCollectionFetches();
...
        if ( needsDistincting ) {
            int includedCount = -1;
            // NOTE : firstRow is zero-based
            int first = !hasLimit || queryParameters.getRowSelection().getFirstRow() == null
                        ? 0
                        : queryParameters.getRowSelection().getFirstRow();
            int max = !hasLimit || queryParameters.getRowSelection().getMaxRows() == null
                        ? -1
                        : queryParameters.getRowSelection().getMaxRows();
            List tmp = new ArrayList();
            IdentitySet distinction = new IdentitySet();
            for ( final Object result : results ) {
                if ( !distinction.add( result ) ) {
                    continue;
                }
                includedCount++;
                if ( includedCount < first ) {
                    continue;
                }
                tmp.add( result );
                // NOTE : ( max - 1 ) because first is zero-based while max is not...
                if ( max >= 0 && ( includedCount - first ) >= ( max - 1 ) ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            results = tmp;
        }
```

In the case of HQL or JPQL queries you can use [PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH hint](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/QueryHints.html#PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH) to have the same effect. Details are described in [The best way to use the JPQL DISTINCT keyword with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpql-distinct-jpa-hibernate/) as mentioned Simon.

Comment: So the summary is: if `getEntityGraphQueryHint() != null`, then the resultset `needsDistincting` regardless of whether `query.getSelectClause().isDistinct()` or not. Nice find, thank you!

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is helpful to improve my insight.

Answer (score 0):

EntityGraph and JOIN FETCH are not related and also not implemented the same way.

The reason for the cartesian product is the back reference from Reply to post. With a uni-directional relationship there wouldn't be a cartesian product.

Please read this excellent article by Vlad Mihalcea about JOIN FETCH

https://vladmihalcea.com/jpql-distinct-jpa-hibernate/